# Ways to formalise $\text{Ring}\approx \text{Group}\times \text{Monoid}$.

Tags: category-theory

In a (unit) ring, elements (of a set $S$) are able to operate on each other via $\cdot,+$. If we are to consider the maps $M:S\times S\to S:(a,b)\mapsto a+b$ and $G:S \times S \to S: (a,b )\mapsto a\cdot b$, we have that $\left \langle S,M \right \rangle$ is a monoid and $\left \langle S,G \right \rangle$ is a group. If we define the composition of maps in $G$ and $M$ such that they are distributive, we have a unit ring.

It is clear that many abstract-algebraic objects (fields, commutative rings, etc.) can arise from taking the 'product' of two other objects in a method similar to above.

Is there a category-theoretical way to view the 'product' of two abstract-algebraic objects in a general sense? Are there any applications of this?

Comment: You can talk about the notion of internalization. A ring is a monoid internal to the monoidal category of abelian groups (with the tensor product), for example. There are some more naive approaches but they fail because they don't specify the correct compatibility conditions (e.g. for rings distributivity is the correct compatibility condition).

Answer (score 6):

The monad of rings is the composite of a *distributive law* of the monad for monoids over the monad for abelian groups. Cf. Jon Beck, "Distributive laws", Lecture Notes in Mathematics 80, p. 119-140, 1969.

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+law

Answer (score 3):

To some extent the answer is yes. There is a structure known as an operad, or a multicategory, which is basically just like a category only morphisms may have tuples of objects as domains, instead of just a single object. Any category with a monoidal product gives rise to an operad simply by considering the analogue of functions of several variables.

All those operads form a category, an extension of the category of categories (ignoring size issue, otherwise insert 'small' where needed). The category of operads has a very interesting and quite complicated tensor products known as the Boardman-Vogt tensor product. With respect to that tensor product the category of operads is closed.

Now the fun begins. For many algebraic structures $p$, such as monoids, commutative monoids, magmas (but not for all algebraic structure, e.g., groups) there is an operad $P$ such that the internal hom object $[P,Q]$ models the operad (and thus a category plus more structure) of all $p$-structures in $Q$. In particular, there is an operad $As$ such that $[As,Set]$, the latter viewed as an operad via the cartesian product of sets, is precisely the operad of associative monoids. Similarly, there is an operad $Comm$ for commutative operads etc.

The Boardman-Vogt tensor product gives a way to construct operads modeling $p$-structures in $p'$-structures, simply because $[P,[Q,R]]\cong[P\otimes Q,R]$. For instance, $[As,[As,Set]]$ models associative monoids in associative monoids, that is, a set with two compatible monoid structures. And this is essentially the same as $[As\otimes As, Set]$. It can be shown (this is not hard) that $As\otimes As\cong Comm$, showing that associative monoids in associative monoids are commutative monoids.

The situation gets much more complicated. See for instance [Fiedorowicz and Boardman](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1311). For a slow-paced intro I shamelessly  recommend [From Operads to Dendroidal Sets](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4315).

Comment: Do operads really answer the question? There's no operad for groups, so you can't simply take $``Grp" \otimes As$.

Comment: Monoids are known as *associative* by their very definition. Why do you emphasize it each time?

Comment: @Berci you are right, it just came out this way.